# PDO select statement stuck in the part where it asks database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with PDO SELECT, I tried get data from the DB but when the function get request to `PDO->prepare` freezes and nothing happens , as if stuck in the part where it asks database, cause the first `ECHO` working. I tried change the SQL syntax with `(`column`= 'value')`, but still the same result. This source code is a part of function in class I use the OOP for this app. pls help, thx.
IN `var_dump()` nothing to show looks like the function dont pass trought the PDO.

```
public function changePswd($old_pswd, $new_pswd, $user_id) {
        echo $old_pswd . "<br/>" . $new_pswd . "<br/>" . $user_id;
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM zamestnanci WHERE id='" . $user_id . "'");
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $hash_pswd = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $hash_pswd;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception('DATABASE ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        var_dump($hash_pswd);
```

Comment: replace your `throw new Exception` with an `echo`. Most probably you have error display turned off.

Comment: Throwing an exception inside a catch clause renders the try/catch essentially useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, sorry I was rash. The problem was in the returned value in TRY part of TRY/CATCH. Because the TRY/CATCH break all progress in function when take return value.

There is a succes: the function for change password (HASH + SALT) / comapre + update

```
public function changePswd($old_pswd, $new_pswd, $user_id) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT password,SALT FROM zamestnanci WHERE id='" . $user_id . "'");
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $hash_pswd = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception('DATABASE ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        $make_pword = sha1($hash_pswd['SALT']) . sha1($old_pswd);
        if ($make_pword === $hash_pswd['password']) {

            function rand_chars_salt($count = 8, $chars = 36) {
                $return = "";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                    $rand = rand(0, $chars - 1);
                    $return .= chr($rand + ($rand < 10 ? ord('0') : ($rand < 36 ? ord('a') - 10 : ord('A') - 36)));
                }
                return $return;
            }

            $SALT = rand_chars_salt();
            $pass_finalize = sha1($SALT) . sha1($new_pswd);
            try {
                $this->_stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE zamestnanci SET `SALT`='" . $SALT . "',`password`='" . $pass_finalize . "' WHERE id='" . $user_id . "'");
                $this->_stmt->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                throw new Exception('DATABASE ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
            echo "<center><span><b>Heslo úspěšně změněno</b><span><center>";
        } else {
            echo "<center><span><b>Staré heslo se neshoduje</b><span><center>";
```

}
    }